# Rolling tables limited to a certian size (i.e. doing first in, first out on a table if its size is > y)

Tags: sql

I have a database full of log entries that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE event_log (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    message VARCHAR(1024),
    sent INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);
```

How would you go about limiting the size of this database like in this pseudocode with x = row count to insert and y = an arbitrary number of rows to limit the table to.

```
On inserting x number of rows:
{
    if (total rows in table + x > y)
    {
        remove x number of rows form the start of the table (i.e. they have lowest id numbers)
    }
    insert the new rows at the end of the table
}
```

i.e. limiting the table to y number of rows max.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to achieve what you try using a trigger. How you do that would depend on the database you are using. You can have a look at the [trigger page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) in wikipedia.